# How To Use WP_Query To Get The Custom Post type Posts With Keywords

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I want to query with keywords and display some related posts on custom taxonomy page, the related posts comes from a custom post type "gift". I have tried the code below, but it only worked for default post_type, how to make it to work for custom post_type? Many thanks!

```
    <?php
    $querytitle = $reltopic; //$reltopic is query keywords
    $querytitle=strtoupper($querytitle);
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE UCASE(post_title) LIKE '%$querytitle%' AND post_type='gift' AND post_status='publish'");
    if ($ids) {
      $args=array(
        'post__in' => $ids,
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        //echo 'List of Posts';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
          <?php
        endwhile;
      }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to pass the post type to your `WP_Query` arguments as well.

By default, `post_type` is set to `post`

A few notes:

- `caller_get_posts` is long time depreciated, you should use `ignore_sticky_posts`
- You should make sure that you have post ID's before passing it to `post__in`. Passing an empty array to `post__in` will return all posts regardless

Comment: Hi Pieter, i forgot to pass the post_type to WP_Query arguments. After added it, the code is working. Thank you very much!